# Is there a way to install a imei on a samsung galaxy s9

Tags: imei

I have a samsung Galaxy S9 that has no Imei Installed I was wondering if there is any way of boot loading or forcing a imei on to the system it is a retail phone

Comment: As far as I remember Samsung usually stores the IMEI info in some special partition called EFS. There are some tutorials online how to recover/repair such a EFS partition. Normally in all custom ROM tutorials there is a big warning that you have to backup this partition first.